# Module Not Found Error:No module named ‘django’これを解決するにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: python, django, pycharm

コマンドプロンプトでpip install djangoで使えるようにしてあります。なぜこのエラーが出るのか教えてください。また、解決策はどうすれば良いのか教えてください。お願いします！

Comment: お使いの環境を質問文に追記してくださいませんでしょうか。また、仮想環境は使ってらっしゃいますか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お疲れ様です。
（別の方がコメントされているよう、もう少し、情報を増やされたほうが回答が得やすいかもしれません。想像半分で以下に回答します。）

import django
が嫌われることは普通ないと想像します。
よって、
pycharmというタグがありますが、pycharmを使われていますか。
で、anacondaも使われていますか。
そのような前提で、
これは、**djangoを別のところにインストールされている**のだと思うので、
元々、インストールした方法で、djangoをuninstalし、
次に、ご使用の環境で進められているインストール方法で、anacondaならば、pipでなくて、
conda等でインストールされるのがいいと思います。

Comment: ご想像の通りpycharm とanacondaを使っていました！仰っていただいた方法で進めたいと思います！ありがとうございます！